# Over Delay with OfflineSync azure mobile - XamarinForms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to pull records and store in a local, to support offline functionality.

But It is taking too much of time to get the records from the server, sometimes it is not finishing the sync process. Even I tried with adding conditions to sync only few records but no luck!.

We will be defining tables:

```
  public void DefineTables(MobileServiceSQLiteStore store)
    {
        //store.DefineTable<TodoItem>();

        store.DefineTable<User>();
    }
```

And we will be pulling records by creating query & query name:

```
 public async Task GetTableDetails<T>(ICloudService cloudService, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null) where T : AtekMobile.Abstractions.TableData
    {
        var table = await cloudService.GetSyncTableAsync<T>();
        var query = filter != null
                    ? table.MobileServiceSyncTable.CreateQuery().Where(filter)
                    : table.MobileServiceSyncTable.CreateQuery();
        var queryName = GetQueryName<T>();
        await table.PullAsync(queryName, query);
    }
```

Am I missing anything? Does anyone faced this issue? Am I doing something wrong? 
Please let me know if i am missing anythings. It is taking long time to sync records.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please verify what region you are in?

Comment: Region is South East Asia!

Comment: How much of a load you are working with?

Comment: @gayan1991 are you asking about number of records? single table may contain atleast 10k records. Here, i'm trying to sync 23 tables.

Comment: yeah.. whats your max page size?

Comment: No page size, I'm syncing all the records from Database to mobile